# Jquery Animate not working for some reason

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I had the 1st half working great. When I tried to add a .mouseleave in the completion function it just froze the whole thing up. can anyone see where I've messed up?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#TwitterBox').mouseenter(function(event) {
        $(this).animate({
            top: 0
        }, {
            duration: 'slow',
            easing: 'easeOutBack',
            complete: function() {
                $('#TwitterBox').mouseleave(function(event) {
                    $(this).animate({
                        top: 550
                    }, {
                        duration: 'slow',
                        easing: 'easeOutBack'
                    });
                });
            }
        });

    });
});​
```

here is the CSS

```
#TwitterWrap{
    background-color: #999;
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    bottom: 25px;
}
#TwitterBox{
    background-color: #0FC;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 450px;
}
```

Essentially just trying to slide a div up on .mouseenter and back down on .mouseleave

Comment: Why are you nesting events like that? Doesn't seem right...

Comment: That's just it I don' think it is. I was getting cofused with braces. The result I have now is what JSlint told me was valid.

Comment: I figured it out. Will post tomorrow when they allow me answer my own question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
I figured it out
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#TwitterBox').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this)
        .animate(
            { top: 50 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
                easing: 'easeOutBack',
                complete: (function() {
$('#TwitterWrap').mouseleave(function() {
    $('#TwitterBox')
        .animate(
            { top: 425 }, {
                duration: 'slow',
                easing: 'easeOutBack',
            })
    });
    })
       })

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand animation. This may help

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#TwitterBox').mouseenter(function(event) {
        $(this).animate({
            top: 0
        }, {
            duration: 'slow',
            easing: 'easeOutBack'
        }
        ).mouseleave(function(event) {
                $(this).animate({
                    top: 300
                }, {
                    duration: 'slow',
                    easing: 'easeOutBack'
                });
            });
    });​
});
```

And click here for **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/safarov/Ympyy/)**